# Parse events from an .ics file in Python

Tags: python, date, calendar, icalendar

Basically my goal is I want to be able to take an ics file as the input and be able to parse out a date's events and then from each event break down the information from it. I have been attempting to figure it out with http://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar

This is as far as I've gotten..

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
cal = Calendar.from_ical(open('Work.ics','rb').read())

for component in cal.walk():
    print component
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending what you mean by 'parse events dates': should you mean the ability to know all instances dates (RRULE, RDATE, EXDATE) you could also try [pyICSParser a ics events enumerator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyICSParser/0.6.1x7), to list instances of events:

```
mycal = icalendar.ics()
mycal.local_load("work.ics")
dates = mycal.get_event_instances(start,end)
#dates will contain the json with all explicit dates of the events spec'ed by the iCalendar file
```

PS: disclaimer - I wrote/still writing this module and it so far only handles DATE not DATE-TIME properties values.

Comment: unfortunately this description is outdated, if someone wishes to try that one, have a look in the installed test.py to figure out how it works now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
with Calendar.from_ical(open("work.ics")) as FileObj:
    for components in FileObj:
        print components
```

This should print every line in file (untested).

Comment: I got `TypeError: <icalendar.prop.vDDDTypes object at 0x108745690> is not JSON serializable`